# Make React pages only visible to authenticated users? (Using Django DRF for backend)

Tags: reactjs, django, django-rest-framework

I have my JWT authentication working and I can sign up and log in via my React project, and I want to redirect the authenticated users to the homepage, where the Nav Bar will say 'log out' rather than 'log in' and 'sign up'.

In Django, I would just place a {% if user.is_authenticated %} in my template, but I'm not sure how to approach this from React itself.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you can save your token on cookies later fetch your token from cookies then define it then if the token is available then show Logout otherwise login Menu.

```
import Cookies from 'universal-cookie';
const cookies = new Cookies();

let token = cookies.get('Token')

return(
    <div>
        {token ? (
            <ul>
                <li>Logout</li>
            </ul>
        ): (
            <ul>
                <li>Login</li>
                <li>Signup</li>
            </ul>
        )}
    </div>
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply! This is one of the first times I'm working with React and Django, and the "?" after "token" is confusing me a little bit. What does it symbolise in this context?

Comment: Read here It will clear concept [Link](https://javascript.plainenglish.io/what-does-the-question-mark-mean-in-javascript-code-353cfadcf760) @CaioIshikawa